# Start gnome as another user on display :1

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell, gnome-session

I logged in a console as a second user and I tried running `startx`, `xinit`, `gnome-session`, `gnome-shell` and all their combinations (in bg `&`). X starts in display :1, I see the mouse pointer, but I don't see any background or gnome panels.

How do I make gnome start as another user on display :1, just like it is normally started by gdm when I log in, with all the panels, the background, multiple desktops, etc?

(Debian testing, gnome3)

Comment: Are you talking about GNOME 2 or GNOME 3?

Comment: GNOME 3, it's in the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :
`~$ sudo DISPLAY=:1 gnome-session`
it will normally start a gnome-session in display :1

Comment: Not sure the exact reason for the downvote as I didn't do it. (maybe the person who did, could advise why!), but you might want to expand your answer to include cases where 'normally' wouldn't apply.